# ASP.net C# Repeater multiple objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following situation:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:ImageButton OnClick="imgSearchResult_Click" BackColor="#333333" ID="imgSearchResult" height="32" width="32" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("ToolTip") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>'/> 
        <asp:Label ID="labValue" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' runat="server" Width="32" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The Repeater contains ImageButton and Label objects. If I only use one object, I can add them from codebehind through the binding:

```
Repeater.DataSource = imageList;
Repeater.DataBind();
```

OR

```
Repeater.DataSource = labelList;
Repeater.DataBind();
```

How can I add both to one Repeater?

Comment: How are the `imageList` and `labelList` related?

Comment: Not at all, I just need them in one Repeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need them in one Repeater, they -are- related in that "view" (loosely used term) of the data. So why not make that view into an explicit object that contains both the image and the label? Either named, or anonymous:

```
return Enumerable.Zip(imageList, labellist, (image, label) => new {image, label})
```

Alternatively, you can just pass the images and query for the labels by index:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="labValue" Text='<%# GetLabelText(Container.ItemIndex) %>' runat="server" Width="32" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This requires a public `GetLabelText(index)` method and probably extra state in your code behind to make the ImageList available to that method. Not very nice, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I see. That seems to work quite well. Thank you very much :)